# Most Reoccurring Text Between 2 Dates Excel

Tags: excel, formula

Got a bit of a pickle. Trying to find the most used delivery company for orders in a specific month. Say the company was in Column A, and order date was in Column B, how would I go about finding the most repeated value?

I've been searching to find a solution but can't find anything, had even considered manually going through but there's over 2000 entries each month aha

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=LET(rng,FILTER(A:A,(B:B>=DATE(2022,01,01))*(B:B<DATE(2022,02,01))),
    INDEX(rng,MODE.SNGL(MATCH(rng,rng,0))))
```

This will return the most frequent for the month of January for 2022.

[image]

E:F is just there to prove that it is returning the most reoccurring text.

Comment: I would add the year in the check, just in case the data goes over multiple years, but yes that works also.